# Apache Camel - How to set a private key in a dynamic sftp endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

Using Java DSL, I have a route in which I poll a file in an SFTP server using the file name set in the message headers

```
from("direct:download")
        .pollEnrich()
        .simple("sftp://my.host:22/folder/?username=foo&fileName=${header.CamelFileName}")
        .to("file://state/downloaded");
```

The sftp endpoint needs to have set a private key. Usually something like this suffices:

```
        endpoint("sftp://my.host:22/folder/?username=foo&fileName=my_file_explicitly_written_here", SftpEndpoint.class).getConfiguration().setPrivateKey(getSshPrivateKey());
```

However, I see no way to "mix" dynamic fields in the URI (`${header.CamelFileName}`) in the `pollEnrich().simple()`) with endpoint configuration.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference `privateKey` as bean from registry.

```
.pollEnrich()
    .simple("sftp://my.host:22/folder/?username=foo&privateKey=#myKeyInRegistry&fileName=${header.CamelFileName}")
```

Binding bean to registry depends on platform and Camel version you are using.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't thought about putting it directly in the uri. That helped!