# Camel SFTP component - SSH private key URI works with privateKeyFile, doesn't work with privateKey

Tags: java, apache-camel, jsch

I have a camel route that looks like the next one:

```
from("direct:download")
        .pollEnrich()
        .simple("sftp://my.host:22/folder/?username=foo&fileName=${header.CamelFileName}
        &privateKeyFile=src/main/resources/privateSSHKey")
        .to("file://state/downloaded");
```

The file src/main/resources/privateSSHKey is an RSA private key. That works without a problem : JSCH (library used by Camel for the SFTP endpoint) manages to connect and download the desired file.

The previous setup is ok while developing, because I can have the file with the key locally.
However, for prod, we have other system in which I will be able to get a byte array with the content of the key. For that, I am changing the route to look like this:

```
from("direct:download")
        .pollEnrich()
        .simple("sftp://my.host:22/folder/?username=foo&fileName=${header.CamelFileName}
     &privateKey=" + URLEncoder.encode(new String(sshPrivateKey), "UTF-8"))
        .to("file://state/downloaded");
```

...being sshPrivateKey the byte array. Unfortunately, I always get "auth_cancel" from JSCH, and debugging I can see that this happens when trying to handshake with the SFTP server.

Am I missing something? I am pretty sure that encoding the sshPrivateKey byte[] is the way to go (JSCH was complaining about wrong key if I didn't do it), but I am not sure about what else I am missing?

Comment: Store byte array of private key in registry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396184/apache-camel-how-to-set-a-private-key-in-a-dinamic-sftp-endpoint

Comment: @raspayu did you managed to solve this problem? I have exactly the same problem and I don't quite understand how can I set my private key in a registry and why

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the problem is the encoding, the URLEncoding, `byte` and `String` can loose some character like `+` or `\\`.
I managed to make it work with `Byte[]` parameter for `privateKey` method Java DSL.

Example:

```java
String privateKeyString = Files.readString(Path.of("/.ssh/private_key_rsa"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

getCamelContext().getRegistry().bind("myPrivateKey", privateKeyString.toByteArray())

from("file://tmp")
.to(sftp("localhost")
        .username("test")
        .privateKey("#myPrivateKey"));
```